# source.on is not a function

Tags: node.js, express

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const axios = require("axios");
var FormData = require('form-data');
var data = new FormData();
router.post('/someroute', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        data.append("ImageFiles", req.files.ImageFiles) // in ImageFiles storing signle object
        const result = await axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'someurl',
            headers: {'Authorization': req.headers['authorization'], ...data.getHeaders()},
            data: data
        }).catch((e) => console.log(e, "error"));
        console.log(result);
    } catch (error){
        console.log(error, "error")
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

if i add JSON.stringify it will work, but another backend always think that it's not string.

Error stack

```js
[0] TypeError: source.on is not a function
[0]     at Function.DelayedStream.create (C:\Users\someuser\PhpstormProjects\someuser\someproject\node_modul
es\delayed-stream\lib\delayed_stream.js:33:10)
[0]     at FormData.CombinedStream.append (C:\Users\someuser\PhpstormProjects\someuser\someproject\node_modu
les\combined-stream\lib\combined_stream.js:45:37)
[0]     at FormData.append (C:\Users\someuser\PhpstormProjects\someuser\someproject\node_modules\form-data\l
ib\form_data.js:75:3)
[0]     at C:\Users\someuser\PhpstormProjects\someuser\someproject\routes\api\proctoring\proctoring.js:18:14
[0]     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\someuser\PhpstormProjects\someuser\someproject\node_mo
dules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
[0]     at next (C:\Users\someuser\PhpstormProjects\someuser\someproject\node_modules\express\lib\router\rou
te.js:137:13)
[0]     at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\someuser\PhpstormProjects\someuser\someproject\node_modules\express\lib\
router\route.js:112:3)
[0]     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\someuser\PhpstormProjects\someuser\someproject\node_mo
dules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
[0]     at C:\Users\someuser\PhpstormProjects\someuser\someproject\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:
281:22
[0]     at Function.process_params (C:\Users\someuser\PhpstormProjects\someuser\someproject\node_modules\exp
ress\lib\router\index.js:335:12) error
```

If i add JSON stringify, it will work. But it's not accurate. Please help. I sending img from backend to another backend

Comment: You are mixing two asynchronous concepts,
awaiting an async procedure does not require a .catch

Comment: But this is not the reason for the error

Comment: What's the full error stack? Where did you add `JSON.stringify` to make it work? It's not clear

Comment: @slideshowp2 thanks, i added error stack. It will work if i add JSON.stringify in data.append("ImageFiles", JSON.stringify(req.files.ImageFiles)). But another backend will not parse it in object